# Binomial Distribution PMF/CDF Identity

Tags: binomial-distribution

I was solving a puzzler and I came across an identity that I've never seen before.  I consulted a couple stats experts and textbooks and have come up empty.  I'm wondering if anyone has ever seen this before.

Let $f(k, n, p)$ and $F(k, n, p)$ be the PMF and CDF of the binomial distribution, respectively.  Then it appears that:

$F(k, 2k+1, p) = F(k, 2k+2, p) + \frac{1}{2} f(k+1, 2k+2, p)$

Haven't formally proved this.  I'm guessing it's not too difficult; maybe needs some of the binomial coefficient recurrence identities.  But I just wanted to ask if anyone has come across this before or if it's a well-known identity.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the relevant rows of Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a lovely opportunity to one-up some other statistics experts!  The formula you are looking at is a special case of a more general identity for the binomial distribution, in the box below.  Taking $n=2k+1$ gives the specific result you are looking at.

$$\boxed{\quad F(k,n,p) = F(k,n+1,p) + \frac{k+1}{n+1} \cdot f(k+1,n+1,p). \quad}$$

Incidentally, this identity is extremely useful for examining the stochastic ordering properties of a binomial random variable.  Specifically, since this identity implies that $F(k,n+1,p) \geqslant F(k,n,p)$ (with strict inequality for $p>0$) it shows that the sequence of random variables $X_n \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ is *stochastically nondecreasing* in $n$ (and *stochastically increasing* in $n$ if $p>0$).

---

**Derivation:** Using Pascal's recurrence identity we can establish the general identities:

$$\begin{align}
F(k,n+1,p)
&= \sum_{i=0}^k {n+1 \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n+1-i} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^k \bigg[ {n \choose i} + {n \choose i-1} \bigg] p^i (1-p)^{n+1-i} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n+1-i} + \sum_{i=1}^k {n \choose i-1} p^i (1-p)^{n+1-i} \\[6pt]
&= (1-p) \sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} + p \sum_{i=1}^k {n \choose i-1} p^{i-1} (1-p)^{n-(i-1)} \\[6pt]
&= (1-p) \sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} + p \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} {n \choose i} p^{i} (1-p)^{n-i} \\[12pt]
&= (1-p) F(k,n,p) + p F(k-1,n,p), \\[20pt]
f(k+1,n+1,p)
&= {n+1 \choose k+1} p^{k+1} (1-p)^{n-k} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n+1}{k+1} {n \choose k} p^{k+1} (1-p)^{n-k} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n+1}{k+1} \cdot p {n \choose k} p^{k} (1-p)^{n-k} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n+1}{k+1} \cdot p f(k,n,p). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

We can combine these results to get:

$$\begin{align}
F(k,n+1,p)
&= (1-p) F(k,n,p) + p F(k-1,n,p) \\[12pt]
&= F(k,n,p) - p [ F(k,n,p) - F(k-1,n,p) ] \\[12pt]
&= F(k,n,p) - p f(k,n,p) \\[12pt]
&= F(k,n,p) - \frac{k+1}{n+1} \cdot f(k+1,n+1,p), \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$

which can be rewritten as the boxed formula above.

Comment: Thank you!  I had a suspicion it was a special case of a more general identity.  Definitely don't remember coming across this in my undergrad probs and stats class.  :-)

Comment: It only really comes up if you look at stochastic dominance properties of the distribution, which is something that people rarely examine.

Answer (score 3):

**There is a simple probability argument.**  It minimizes the math and intuitively shows why such an equality exists *which does not depend on $p.$*

In the following I will employ just two basic rules of probability: *conditional probabilities multiply* and *mutually exclusive probabilities add.*  You all know what these vague (but memorable) phrases mean, so I won't belabor the details.

For any $n\ge 0,$ consider a sequence of $n+1$ Bernoulli$(p)$ observations $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n+1}$ ("coin flips").  By definition, each random variable has a chance $p$ to equal $1$ and otherwise equals $0.$

$F(k,n)$ is the chance that $k$ or fewer of the first $n$ outcomes equal $1.$  **This can happen in two ways:**

1. **$k$ or fewer of all $n+1$ outcomes equal $1.$**  The chance of this is $\color{blue}{F(k,n+1)}.$
2. **Exactly $k+1$ of the outcomes equal $1$** (the chance of this is written $\color{red}{f(k+1,n+1)})$ **and the final outcome is $1$** (making $k$ of the first $n$ outcomes equal to $1$).

When the $X_i$ are independent (or just exchangeable), all re-orderings of their outcomes are equally likely.  In such cases *we may therefore reconstruct event $(2)$ by starting with a *fixed* sequence of $k+1$ ones and $n-k$ zeros and then distributing the $X_i$ randomly within this sequence.*  Any given $X_i$ thereby (obviously!) has a chance $(k+1)/(n+1)$ of landing on a $1.$ Consequently, the chance of $(2)$ is $\color{red}{f(k+1,n+1)}$ times $(k+1)/(n+1).$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ are *mutually exclusive* because you cannot simultaneously observe $k$ and $k+1$ ones.  Moreover, they are *exhaustive* because there is no other way $k$ or fewer of the first $n$ outcomes can happen.  Thus **$F(k,n)$ must equal the sum of the chances of $(1)$ and $(2):$**

> $$F(k,n) = \color{blue}{F(k,n+1)} + \frac{k+1}{n+1} \color{red}{f(k+1,n+1)}.$$

**The particular value $n=2k+1$ answers the question,** showing that the "$1/2$" in its formula comes from $(k+1)/(2k+1+1) = 1/2.$

The analysis of case $(2)$ did not need to refer to the probability $p.$  This is why $p$ does not appear in the formula.